# Make color change speed be dependent on mouseX

Tags: p5.js, noise

I have a grid of tiles that slowly change colors between red and green. How do I make the color change speed be dependent on mouseX such that small mouseX equals faster color changes.

```
function colorGrid(){
    var stepSize = 20;
    var green = color(0, 255, 0);
    var red = color(255, 0, 0);
    for(var x=0;x<25;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<25;y++){
            var tX = (x*stepSize+frameCount)*0.003;
            var tY = (y*stepSize+frameCount)*0.003;
            var t = noise(tX, tY);
            var c = lerpColor(green, red, t);
            fill(c);
            noStroke();
            rect(x*stepSize,y*stepSize,stepSize,stepSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question would benefit from more details, it is not really clear what you mean by the color change speed be dependent on mouseX. Do you simply want to replace `frameCount` by `mouseX` in your `tX` and `tY` initializations? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @statox Make it such that small mouseX equals faster color changes and big mouseX equals slower color changes. The speed of the color change will depend on the position of my mouseX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to change is the rate at which you move in the noise space. For now you use `frameCount` to move temporally in this space.

So to change the speed you need to play with `frameCount`. One way to do it is to map `mouseX` between `frameCount * 1` (your current behavior) and `frameCount * X` where `X > 1`.

```
function colorGrid(){
    var stepSize = 20;
    var green = color(0, 255, 0);
    var red = color(255, 0, 0);
    // Creating the factor 
    const temporalOffsetFactor = map(mouseX, 0, width, 1, 50);
    for(var x=0;x<25;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<25;y++){
            var tX = (x*stepSize+frameCount*temporalOffsetFactor)*0.003; // Using the new factor
            var tY = (y*stepSize+frameCount*temporalOffsetFactor)*0.003;
            var t = noise(tX, tY);
            var c = lerpColor(green, red, t);
            fill(c);
            noStroke();
            rect(x*stepSize,y*stepSize,stepSize,stepSize);
        }
    }
}
```

See it in action [here](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/bGwdZqP?editors=0011)

---

**Edit** To avoid the map "jumping" when you move the mouse a possible solution is to debouce mouseX to get its value only every X ms (I found that 500ms works quite well). So you could add this to your code before the call to `setup()`

```
let debouncedMouseX = 1;
setInterval(() => (debouncedMouseX = mouseX), 1000);
```

and replace `mouseX` by `debouncedMouseX` in the line `const temporalOffsetFactor = map(mouseX, 0, width, 1, 50);`

That might not be ideal but it can work. I updated my codepend accordingly.

Comment: Ok I don't know if this is a stupid question, but is there a way for the colors to not move at super speed everytime I'm moving the mouse cursor? Like the mouseX color change speed works perfectly fine if my mouse is stationery but everytime I move it, the colors all go haywire. And then I stop moving and it's fine again.

Comment: @ahmadalibin Check my edit I tried to add some deboucing to avoid this kind of jumps.

Comment: I'm using Brackets which uses p5.js and it has parsing error: unexpected token with this line `setInterval(() => (debouncedMouseX = mouseX), 1000);`.

Comment: As you can see [here, on line 2](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/bGwdZqP?editors=0011) it works fine. "Unexpected token" means that you didn't properly formatted the code before this line, check for missing quotes or assignment or any syntax error.

Comment: Ok I'm still able to compile even with the error. I'm not sure whether it's better with debounce or without debounce since it looks really choppy but it does work by stopping "jumping" so I guess it's which one I prefer. Anyway, thanks for all your help. You've been very helpful.

Comment: @ahmadalibin If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted with the green tick on the left so that other users know that you found a satisfying answer and that will give you some reputation points. And it it helped you you can also give it an upvote with the up arrow on the left which will also give me some points.

Comment: Right, sorry I forgot to mark your answer as accepted.